# Custom serverRuntime in deployed WCF site is not working

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have issue in deploying WCF service with max values for server runtime in IIS  but its not work displaying error

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error The requested page cannot be
>   accessed because the related configuration data for the page is
>   invalid.

at following line

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<serverRuntime maxRequestEntityAllowed="4294967295" uploadReadAheadSize="2147483647" />
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

How can I unlock IIS for serverruntime in WCF deployed project